# Creating a null value in a DATE validated column

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

I have a uiApp that is creating table views from spreadsheet data, but I'm having difficulty with empty cells in a date column.

Basically, some of the spreadsheet cells are optional, and I haven't figured out how to put no (or a null) value into the table. Right now it works if I set the column value to:

```
projectDataRaw[i][projectDataKeys[j]]= new Date(); // inserting dummy data
```

But I want to leave those cells blank in the table view too, however, when I use:

```
projectDataRaw[i][projectDataKeys[j]]= null; //
```

Or some variation of that, it errors because the column type is set to DATE.
I could convert to strings, but I kind of wanted to be able to compare date values to each other when they are available.

-- Example of issue with table view and null data --

```
// load data from sheet
var _PMsheet = "sheet key";
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(_PMsheet);
var projectData = sSheet.getRangeByName("ProjectDateCol").getValues();

var projectDataTable = Charts.newDataTable();
projectDataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, "Date Column");

for (var i=0; i < projectData.length; i++) {
  if (projectData[i] == undefined || projectData[i] == "undefined") {
    projectDataTable.addRow([null]);// Object type does not match column type.
    // null fails, "undefined" fails, "" fails, [] fails 
  }
  else {
    projectDataTable.addRow([projectData[i]]); // this cell has a valid date obj
  }

}
```

Comment: How about 
projectDataRaw[i][projectDataKeys[j]]= "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple script which writes null to the A1 cell and current date to the A2 cell. The complete column A is validated to be a date time. After the script execution the cell A1 is empty even if it contained a value before and there is no any warning or error message.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rangeValues = [[null], [new Date()]];
  sheet.getRange("A1:A2").setValues(rangeValues);
}
```

If this example does not help you, please publish as smallest as possible working script which does not work as you expected.

**Update, basing on the author clarification:** I wrote a simple script trying to find the problem cause and to find a workaround. The code is bellow. If to uncomment the `data.addRow(['', 2.0]);` line, then an exception thrown by the `addRow` method. It is an expected behavior. If to uncomment the `data.addRow([null, 3.0]);` line, then the `chart.setDataTable(data)` line throws an exception. This behavior is not correct, from my point of view, and I think it is necessary to report an issue to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Also there is a workaround of this problem by using the [DataTableBuilder.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_datatablebuilder#setValue) method. The code demonstrates it.

By the way, the `DataTableBuilder.setValue` description in the documentation is not correct. It does not contain the `column` parameter. It is a topic to the issue tracker.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var chart = Charts.newTableChart();
  var data = Charts.newDataTable();
  data.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE, 'Date');
  data.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Value');
  data.addRow([new Date(), 1.0]);
//  data.addRow(['', 2.0]); // throws the "Object type does not match column type" exception in this line.
//  data.addRow([null, 3.0]); // throws the "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again" exception in the "chart.setDataTable(data)" line.
  data.setValue(1, 1, 3.0);
  chart.setDataTable(data);
  app.add(chart.build());
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I posted a more in-depth code example. My issue is with the Charts.newDataTable and accepting a null value in a DATE column. Thanks.

Comment: Just to follow up. I reported the issue here: [issue 1832](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1832&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)